# REGEXP_REPLACE in Teradata SQLA

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to remove the date part at the end of comment data in text in a column. The date at the end is like `21FEB`,`2004/21FEB` and `21FEB18`.

I used

```
RegExp_Replace(X, ' [0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{3}$','',1,1,'i')
```

to remove `21FEB` at the end of a comment like `ADDED EMAIL ADDRESS FROM CTCE DATA 21FEB`.

I used

```
RegExp_Replace(X, ' [0-9]{1,4}/[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{3}$','',1,1,'i')
```

to remove `2004/21FEB` at the end of a comment like `REX AUTO REFUND 2004/21FEB`.

I used

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(X, ' [0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}$','',1,1,'i')
```

to remove `21FEB18` at the end of a comment like `CANCELED DUPLICATED SEGMENTS P 21FEB18`.

Is there a way to combine all these 3 different variants of the REGEXP_REPLACE function in a single REGEXP_REPLACE expression so that it applies to the different comment formats?

Comment: Be careful as you are not really checking for dates, but digits with 3 letters.  Comments can contain anything a user enters so to really check for a month you should be checking that the letters part matches (JAN|FEB|MAR...), you get the idea. What if your comment is `DON'T DELETE the secret code 99XYZ`?  That should not be touched. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `DDMMM` part is always included and there might be two optional parts,  `YYYY/` before and `YY` after it:

```
RegExp_Replace(X, ' ([0-9]{1,4}/)?[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{3}([0-9]{1,2})?$','',1,1,'i')
```